# Azure Timer Trigger: Cron expression for every hour on the hour

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions, timer-trigger

Whats the cron expression for every hour on the hour?
I tried this '0 0 * ? * *' but it threw an error
I have a Azure function timer trigger

This expression below runs every minute on the minute.

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

Here is the error I received when I tried "0 0 * ? * * *" and "0 0 * ? * *"

> [11/22/2018 12:45:29 AM] A ScriptHost error has occurred
>   [11/22/2018 12:45:29 AM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Currencies.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions: The schedule expression '0 0 * ? * * *' was not recognized as a valid cron expression or timespan string.
>   [11/22/2018 12:45:29 AM] Error indexing method 'Currencies.Run'
>   [11/22/2018 12:45:29 AM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Currencies.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions: The schedule expression '0 0 * ? * * *' was not recognized as a valid cron expression or timespan string.

Comment: I tried this and received an error message. I'll post the error message above

Comment: yes that works but it runs every minute on the minute, not every hour like I want

Comment: @user1186050 Have you tried `0 0 * * * *`?

Comment: no I'm trying that now, but I'll have to wait until the next hour to see if it works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: Try using `"0 0 * * * *"`, the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions) emphasizes the use of six fields.

> Azure Functions uses the NCronTab library to interpret CRON expressions. A CRON expression includes **six** fields:
>
> {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}

---

Azure supposedly uses the [`NCrontab`](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) library according to the doco, but testing suggests otherwise!  <s>so use `"0 * * * *"` for every hour on the hour.</s>

Here's the [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) script to verify:

```
var s = CrontabSchedule.Parse("0 * * * *");
var start = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
var end = start.AddYears(1);
var occurrences = s.GetNextOccurrences(start, end);
occurrences.Dump();
```

[This needs the NCrontab nuget package pulled in]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer

> "Azure Functions uses the NCronTab library to interpret CRON
> expressions"

Comment: I just tried "0 * * * *" and received the same formatting error. Did you miss a character? "The schedule expression '0 * * * *' was not recognized as a valid cron expression or timespan string"

Comment: It looks like it only wants to accept a 6 digit format as valid. If I use your format, what would it be with six digits? 0 0 * * * * ?

Comment: How can I test this without waiting until the next hour?

Comment: how do you get that Dump method plz?

Comment: @kevinob: it's part of LINQPad's extension methods.